# Why is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{Q}$ not a finitely generated $\Bbb{Q}$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules, extension-field

Let $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ be the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{Q}$. I am trying to show that $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ is not finitely generated as a $\Bbb{Q}$-module, however I do not know where to go with this.

I have tried assuming that $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ is finitely generated by $x_1, \ldots , x_r$ and then saying that if $\alpha \in \overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ then there is an $f \in \Bbb{Q}[X]$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$, but I cannot see where to go from here to obtain a contradiction.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Exhibit an infinite list of linearly independent elements of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: It's overkill in this case, but the Artin-Schreier theorem describes fields $k$ with $[\overline{k}:k]$ finite. In particular, they contain an element $x$ with $x^2 = -1$, which $\mathbb{Q}$ lacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A finitely generated $\mathbb Q$-module is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

There are elements in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ of arbitrarily high degree and so $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ cannot be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

For instance, $x^n-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ for every $n$ and so $2^{1/n}$ is an element of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ of degree $n$. The $\mathbb Q$-subspace generated by $2^{1/n}$ has dimension $n$.

Note that this proves that $\overline{\mathbb Q} \cap \mathbb R$ is not a finitely generated $\mathbb Q$-module. You don't even need to consider complex numbers.

Comment: What do you mean of arbitrarily high degree?

Comment: The "and so" might need some justification.

Comment: @AaAaAa It means, that $n$ can be arbitrarily high for $x^n-2$.

Comment: Ok so I understand how $2^{1/n}$ is an element of $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ for every $n$, but what exactly do you mean by $2^{1/n}$ having degree $n$?

Comment: @AaAaAa, it means that the polynomial of least degree having $2^{1/n}$ as a root has degree $n$. For your purposes, this means that $\{2^{k/n} : k=0, \dots, n-1 \}$  is linearly independent.

Comment: Why exactly are they linearly independent? And is there a way I can put this in a such way that it shows exactly why we cannot have a finite generating set?

Comment: The answer is correct and accurate, imo, for anyone learning Fields Extensions and/or Galois Theory, and thus +1 . Now, "degree" of an algebraic element $\;w\in K\;$ over some subfield $\;F\subset K\;$ is just $\;[K:F]=$ degree of the minimal polynomial of $\;w\;$ in $\;F[x]\;$ . From here everything follows.

Comment: I understand the degree part, the only bit I am struggling with now is why the of powers of $2^{1/n}$ are linearly independent, can you help with that?

Comment: @AaAaAa, a polynomial equation satisfied by $\alpha$ is the same as a relation of linear dependence between powers of $\alpha$.

Comment: Oh I see now thanks very much!